# VBA to select all columns in a worksheet and auto adjust all columns width in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with with over 1000 columns. How can I select all columns in that sheet and auto adjust every column width. I tried

```
Sheets(1).Select
Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

But it didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this...

```
Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Less taxing than autofit on every column. Although, the performance difference on devices nowadays is very minimal, when we code we should always look for a solution that solves our problem while being the most efficient.

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
Cells.Columns.Autofit
```

or, if you're not on the ActiveSheet then

```
Sheets(name_or_number).Columns.Autofit
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a macro to autofit all the sheets in a workbook at once

```
Option Explicit
Sub Auto_Fit()
Dim sh As Worksheet
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
sh.Columns.AutoFit
Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add some explanatory text to your answer using the [edit] button. Code only answers are not helpful to learners.